# Spark Interpreter does not work in Zeppelin

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, interpreter, apache-zeppelin

I am using Zeppelin 0.7.0 to run Spark jobs. My Zeppelin is a standalone installation whereas Spark was installed using Hortonworks/Ambari (version 2.6). When I check the status of Spark in Ambari, it is all green. Zeppelin is running fine too for many interpreters. However the Spark interpreter does not work. Anything I try to do, even something as simple as `sc.version` gives out this exact same error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.Utils.invokeMethod(Utils.java:38)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.Utils.invokeMethod(Utils.java:33)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.open(SparkInterpreter.java:652)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:70)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:483)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:175)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:139)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This error has happened very unexpectedly. The Spark interpreter was working fine until a few weeks ago when this error started popping up. I have restarted both Spark and Zeppelin but the error persists. No changes were made in the configuration files of either Zeppelin or Spark to cause this.

Comment: Can you try running a Spark shell from the SPARK_HOME that Zeppelin is using?

Comment: Yes, the spark shell opens fine and I can run commands.

Comment: Hmm. Is there a particular reason not to use the Zeppelin provided by HDP?

Comment: I think at the time the Zeppelin that came bundled with that version of HDP had issues (memory leaks) and we decided to use the older version that had fewer issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the interpreter log more, the error you see is due to fail to create SparkContext, you need to check log to see why SparkContext is failed to create.

Comment: @Shankar Koirala I am getting this error while setting up in windows 10  and scala/spark  , any clue what am i missing here  ````
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:689)
    at

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Zeppelin and was fixed with the Interpreter setting.

1. Go to Interpreter and search and select spark `Interpreter`
2. Click edit and add `name` and `value` as   `zeppelin.spark.useHiveContext = false`

Hope this works!

Comment: can you restart the zeppelin after adding ?